# Longest Increasing Sub sequence in a range

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming, subsequence

I have come across a problem where we want to tell the maximum size of the longest increasing sub-sequence.

```
an array A consisting of N integers. 
M queries (Li, Ri)
for each query we wants to find the length of the longest increasing subsequence in 
array A[Li], A[Li + 1], ..., A[Ri].
```

I implemented finding the sub-sequence using dp approach

```
// mind the REPN, LLD, these are macros I use for programming
// LLD = long long int
// REPN(i, a, b) = for (int i = a; i < b; ++i)
LLD a[n], dp[n];
REPN(i, 0, n) 
{ 
  scanf("%lld", &a[i]); 
  dp[i] = 1; 
}
REPN(i, 1, n) 
{
  REPN(j, 0, i) 
  {
    if(a[i] > a[j]) 
      dp[i] = std::max(dp[j] + 1, dp[i]);
  }
}
```

For example:

```
Array: 1 3 8 9 7 2 4 5 10 6
dplis: 1 2 3 4 3 1 3 4 5  5
max: 5
```

But if it was for range `Li=2` & `Ri=9`

Then:

```
Array: 3 8 9 7 2 4 5 10
dplis: 1 2 3 2 1 2 3 4
max: 4
```

How can i determine the maximum longest increasing sub-sequence in a sub array?

**PS:** I don't want to recompute the whole dplis array, I want to use the original one because too much computation will kill the purpose of the question.

One of the approaches was to construct a complete 2D DP array that consists of sub-sequence from position i where range of i is from 0 to n, but it fails on many cases due to **TLE**(Time limit exceeded)

```
REPN(k,0,n) {
    REPN(i,k+1,n) {
        REPN(j,k,i) {
            if(a[i]>a[j]) dp[k][i]=std::max(dp[k][j]+1, dp[k][i]);
        }
    }
} 

REPN(i,0,q) {
    read(l); read(r);

    LLD max=-1;
    REPN(i,0,r) {
        if(max<dp[l-1][i]) max=dp[l-1][i];
    }

    printf("%lld\n", max);
}
```

If you have any new logic/implementation, I will gladly study it in-depth. Cheers.

Comment: Please note that this is a problem from a running contest: https://www.codechef.com/DEC16/problems/SEAINCR It ends at the end of December.

Comment: @NiklasB. I rather not care about winning the contest, I care about solving and enhancing my skills, sorry if you are being offended about this

Comment: In that case it shouldn't be a problem for you to delete this question for now and re-pose it in January, so as to not spoil other peoples' fun

Comment: @NiklasB. and forget till then such a good question exists? PS: i got mine partially correct. I am just into problem solving rather winning, [solution link](https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/12185067)